# MySQL: show only dates within the month of March

Tags: mysql

I am trying to show *only* the dates within the month of March and can't quite figure it out.

***Here is the table...***

[image]

***Here is my current code...***

```
SELECT billing.charged_datetime-- SUM(billing.amount) AS total_revenue
FROM lead_gen_business.billing;
WHERE billing.charged_datetime BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, you have a semi colon after `FROM lead_gen_business.billing` line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` thus you can't just go along with date in the comparison, you also need to provide the time.

Note that before the comparison, the type is converted to match the column type. Have a look into this query for an illustration:

```
SELECT CAST('2015-10-18' AS DATETIME)
```

So one option is to use the condition as follows (assuming no decimals in the data type):

```
WHERE billing.charged_datetime BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-30 23:59:59'
```

The best (readable) option is to however change the condition into:

```
WHERE MONTH(charged_datetime) = 3 AND YEAR(charged_datetime) = 2012
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

*Edit after seeing your comments on other answers. Is this what you were looking for?*

```
SELECT DATE(billing.charged_datetime)
FROM lead_gen_business.billing
WHERE MONTH(billing.charged_datetime) = 3 AND YEAR(billing.charged_datetime) = 2012;
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this doesn't work. All it does is show only the charged_datetime column with all of the content, not just the March dates.

Comment: See the updated answer. Is the `DATE` function what you were looking for?

Comment: The last query in the answers shows you all dates (not the time) from that table which are in March 2012. Isn't that what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: No, it literally don't change anything with the dates at all. There are dates ranging from 2001 - 2015 in there still. :/ But yeah, what you described is what I am trying to achieve...

Comment: Fixed a typo in the query, you can have a look at it now again.

Comment: DING DING DING DING! WE HAVE A WINNER!

Answer (score 1):

Since you enter `Datetime` in `charged_datetime`. You would need to use the `convert` function of mysql.

Use this :-

```
SELECT billing.charged_datetime-- SUM(billing.amount) AS total_revenue
FROM lead_gen_business.billing;
WHERE billing.charged_datetime BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'2012-03-01)' AND CONVERT(datetime,'2012-03-30');
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this doesn't work. All it does is show only the charged_datetime column with all of the content, not just the March dates.

Comment: In your table image that you've uploaded. I don't see any date of the year 2012.

Comment: That is because there are thousands of dates and I took a picture of a few rows to illustrate the table.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong is, your from should have `00:00:00` and your end should have `23:59:59` (assuming seconds precision).

Irrespective, what you'll want is:

```
SELECT billing.charged_datetime
FROM lead_gen_business.billing
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(billing.charged_datetime, "%Y %m") = "2015 March";
```

You should take some time going through the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Lots of insight on when and how to use between and not to.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this doesn't work. All it does is show only the charged_datetime column with all of the content, not just the March dates.